# QTcpSocket Клиент-серверное приложение

Tags: qtcpsocket

Всем привет! начинаю осваивать программирование и фреймворк qt. Вопрос состоит в следующем: допустим у меня есть сервер который обрабатывает запросы. Возникает вопрос, на стороне клиента надо общаться через один сокет или можно создавать несколько? дело в том, что из разных форм я не смог получить доступ к одному главному сокету. Создавая разные сокеты, на сервере SocketDescriptor у всех будет разный, думаю так не должно быть. Как вообще организовать общение клиентской стороны, заранее Спасибо! Или указать соответствующую литературу.